# PyQt5 not found in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt5

I would like to use PyQt5 on my PyCharm but If I try to import it I get

ImportError: No module named PyQt5.

I looked for hours other answers but the issue doesn't seem to be fixed. I'm running MacOS X 10.13, PyCharm 2019.3. What puzzles me is that if on PyCharm I go to

Preferences > Project interpreter

then PyQt5 shows up among the packages that I have installed. Could anybody help?

Comment: Try `pip install PyQt5`. I had a similar problem once. Or before doing that, in PyCharm go to `File` -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart...`

Comment: @mapf : I tried to invalidate caches and restart but it doesn't solve the issue. If I try pip install PyQt5 I get an error message related to Python 2.7 not being mantained. If I try pip3 install PyQt5, the requirement is already satisfied, because I had already installed it. I already checked that PyCharm is using the Python 3.7 interpreter.

Comment: Are you using Anaconda by any chance?

Comment: @mapf : No I don't

Comment: Ok. In my case, I think it had something to do with Anaconda. Sorry.